# Python kivy (kivyMD) how to fetch values of MDDropdownMenu

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to fetch the selection of a `MDDropwdownMenu` inside my kv file I am using a `MDRaisedButton` by the following code

```
 MDRaisedButton:
                            id: select_warning_image_Button
                            text: "Menu labels"                          
                            opposite_colors:    True
                            elevation_normal:    0
                            on_release: MDDropdownMenu(items=app.menu_labels, width_mult=4).open(self)
```

In my `main.py` (see below) I have a class called `MainApp` which inherits from `App`. Inside this class I have created the attribute variable `menu_labels`. I want to use the function `change_variable` to set the value of the variable `VARIABLE` to the value of the menu. But I cannot seem to be able to use self.change_variable(…). Is there a value to fire a function when a specific value in the dropdown is selected?

```
# main.py
import …


class MainApp(App):
    VARIABLE = ""

    menu_labels = [
        {"viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
         "text": "Label1",
         "on_release": self.change_variable("Label1")},
        {"viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
         "text": "Label2",
         "on_release": self.change_variable("Label2")},
    ]

    def change_variable(self, label):
        self.VARIABLE = label
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

In the output, `Label2` was selected. Please refer to the snippet, example and output for details.

## kv file

1. Add a class rule for `<MDMenuItem>:`
2. Add `on_release` event to invoke `change_variable()` method in App class and pass `self.text` to it.

### Snippet - kv file

```
<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release: app.change_variable(self.text)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager


class MainApp(App):
    title = "KivyMD MDDropdownMenu Demo"
    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    VARIABLE = ""

    menu_labels = [
        {"viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
         "text": "Label1"},
        {"viewclass": "MDMenuItem",
         "text": "Label2"},
    ]

    def change_variable(self, value):
        print("\nvalue=", value)
        self.VARIABLE = value
        print("\tself.VARIABLE=", self.VARIABLE)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

### main.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.menu.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.button.MDRaisedButton

<MDMenuItem>:
    on_release: app.change_variable(self.text)

Screen:
    name: 'menu'
    MDRaisedButton:
        id: select_warning_image_Button
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 3 * dp(48), dp(48)
        text: 'Menu labels'
        opposite_colors: True
        elevation_normal:    0
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.9}
        on_release: MDDropdownMenu(items=app.menu_labels, width_mult=4).open(self)
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - MDDropdownMenu opened]
[image: Img02 - Selected Label2]

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I will try this solution and accept the answer if it works :).

Comment: Thank you for your help @ikolim! Your contributions should be added to the official documentation :).

Comment: @ikolim how to make it work if there are multiple dropdowns in the kv? how can we call a different function for each dropdown?

Comment: It is no longer working on KivyMD 1.1.1 even if I change Py file import to `from kivymd.app import MDApp`, inherit from MDApp not App, & in KV change imports to `#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.uix.menu.MDDropdownMenu` and `#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton`. Popup still doesn't appear. Your example is simpler than the [official example](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/wiki/Components-DropDownItem#example-of-using-mddropdownitem) so it would be nice we would get yours working.